# unicode error in list coming from xls going to a csv file

Tags: python, csv, unicode, utf-8, xlrd

I'm trying to scrape an xls file from a page and save it to csv. I've created a function that handles the file, but when I try and write the file out I get an encoding error, saying that it can't handle one of the characters in the file.

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa0' in position 9: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I'm trying to enforce utf-8 across every item in the list using the unicode function, which seems to work on most items, but somehow I'm still getting the same error.

```
def csv_from_excel( fileName ):
# open the xls file and save as a csv

wb = xlrd.open_workbook(fileName)
worksheets = wb.sheet_names()
for worksheet_name in worksheets:
    worksheet = wb.sheet_by_name(worksheet_name)
    print worksheet
    csvfile = open(fileName, 'wb')
    wr = csv.writer(csvfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

    for rownum in xrange(worksheet.nrows):
        cleanrow = [unicode(i) for i in worksheet.row_values(rownum)]
        print cleanrow
        wr.writerow(cleanrow)

    csvfile.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python 2, you need to pass *encoded strings* to the `csv` module, not Unicode values.

```
for rownum in xrange(worksheet.nrows):
    cleanrow = [unicode(i).encode('utf8') for i in worksheet.row_values(rownum)]
    print cleanrow
    wr.writerow(cleanrow)
```

This encodes all values to UTF-8 before passing them on to the writer object.

Calling `unicode()` on objects converts non-unicode values (byte strings, numbers, etc.) to a `unicode` object, not to UTF-8 encoded bytes. Only an explicit `.encode()` method call does that.

Comment: Martijn, thanks so much, that is brilliant, I've been hacking at that problem for hours.